# How do I generate & tangle source code in a different language?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

In an org file, I have a Perl source code block that generates SQL code.  The Perl code is to be part of the exported document, but the SQL code is not; it is supposed to be tangled to the corresponding output source code file only.  If my source block is as follows:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC perl     :results output verbatim code replace   :exports code   
:tangle no  :eval yes
  #!/path/to/perl

  # Do some computations, generates some SQL code.
  print "INSERT INTO mytable (id, num1, num2) VALUES";
  my $comma = '';
  for (my $i=1; $i<=4; $i++)
  {
      my $n1 = 20 + rand(20);
      my $n2 = 60 + rand(60);
      printf "$comma\n    (%5.2f, %6.2f)", $n1, $n2;
      $comma = ',';
  }
  print "\n";
#+END_SRC
```

Then when I evaluate the block with `C-c C-c`, the following results block is inserted:

```
#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_SRC perl
INSERT INTO mytable (id, num1, num2) VALUES
    (1, 21.03,  77.17),
    (2, 28.68,  83.04),
    (3, 31.16,  99.71),
    (4, 21.68,  88.94)
#+END_SRC
```

The problem is the `+#BEGIN_SRC perl` line.  I want it to be

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql    :eval no    :tangle yes    :exports none
```

The only way I've been able to do this is by changing the `code` header in the
Perl source block to `raw`, and adding explicit Perl statements to generate the org headers for the output block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC perl     :results output verbatim raw replace   :exports none   :tangle no  :eval yes
  print "#+BEGIN_SRC sql  :eval no   :tangle yes  :exports none\n";
  # ...REST OF CODE AS ABOVE, THEN:
  print "#+END_SRC\n";
#+END_SRC
```

This does generate the results code block I want, but it seems clumsy and ugly.  Also, the hacky print statements are exported to the output document as part of the Perl code block.  Is there a more elegant way to specify header options on a generated source code block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:wrap` will do what you want (cf. https://orgmode.org/manual/wrap.html).

Try this header.

`#+BEGIN_SRC perl :results output verbatim code replace :exports code :tangle no :eval yes :wrap "SRC sql :eval no :tangle yes :exports none"`

Comment: That did it!  Thanks, I hadn't noticed that option before.